# cv parameter in sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV in regression problems: best_score_ decreases with larger cv values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have problems understanding the effect of the cv parameter in GridSearchCV. I'm still on Python 2.7 with sklearn 0.18

When using GridSearchCV to tune some parameters for e.g. ridge regression, I would expect the scores to go up for a larger number of folds, as more and more data is included in training.
However, I observed the opposite behaviour. Could anyone explain to me, whether this should be expected?

Consider the following example

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import model_selection
import numpy as np

# Some example data
X = np.ones((100, 4)) * np.arange(100).reshape((100, 1)) + (np.random.random((100, 4)) * 0.5)
Y = np.ones((100, 1)) * np.arange(100).reshape((100, 1))
scalerx = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_ = scalerx.fit_transform(X)
scalerx = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
Y_ = scalerx.fit_transform(Y)

for cv in np.arange(2, 100, 5):
    GS = model_selection.GridSearchCV(
        cv=cv, estimator=linear_model.Ridge(random_state=0),
        param_grid=[{'alpha': [10e-2, 10e-1, 10e0, 10e1, 10e2]}],
        )
    GS.fit(X_, Y_)
    print(cv, GS.best_score_)
```

this produces the following output

```
2 0.999967723551
7 0.999700831429
12 0.999157506389
17 0.998278596601
22 0.997107931494
27 0.995490243014
32 0.993315835556
37 0.990634277512
42 0.986174197011
47 0.982697293408
52 0.941176694311
57 0.844045003327
62 0.744867073869
67 0.646916948176
72 0.548521372859
77 0.451907425236
82 0.352978995707
87 0.256264849417
92 0.1575027865
97 0.058902807202
```

The best score decreases with smaller test samples (larger number of folds).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @stephen-rauch, thank you very much for your suggestions. I have fixed the code and hopefully improved the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the data used has a direct impact on the variance of Y. This is important because sklearn's regression models uses R-squared as the default score formula, i. e. mean(y_hat - y) / var(y).

Given the data you provided, as the number of samples increases, the variance decreases, making the R^squared value decrease as well.

"The one situation where R2 can be compared is when different models are
fit to the same data set with the same, untransformed response variable.
Then increasing R2 is the same as decreasing in-sample MSE (by Eq. 9).
In that case, however, you might as well just compare the MSEs."

Page 17 in http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf

Comment: Hi @rafaelvalle and thank you very much for the explanation. So I assume using a leave-one-out approach for tuning parameters doesn't make sense at all, because of the way the R-squared scores are calculated per model and then summarized. Would you say that collecting scores of different models (trained on different subsets) and calculating R-squared over all results (from different models) is a sensible thing to do in this situation?